# How should i change "\\n" to "\n" in string of Java

Tags: java, regex

I have a string a = `"Some \\\n text"`

i want to change it a= `"Some \n text"`

Comment: That is what `String a = "Some \\n text";` **is**. Please clarify your question. Do you want to see a literal ``\\`` in `a`? Show us the expected output (and how you intend to see it).

Comment: Does `a = a.replace("\\n", "\n");` solve your problem? If not please clarify your question.

Comment: I want to change Java regex to JS regex. That's all. Any question?

Comment: And where's your Java regex is ? use this [`Regex tester`](https://regex101.com/) to test your regex

Comment: Please define "change Java regex to JS regex". What do you *really* want to do and what problems are you facing?

Comment: I need to change "abc \\n def" to "abc \n def" That's all

Comment: What what is `"abc \\n def"`? Is it string literal (which appears somewhere in code like `String a = "abc \\n def";`), or maybe data which you got from somewhere (like `String a = scanner.nextLine();` and here scanner returns `"abc \\n def"`). Difference is that in first case ``\\`` will represents single ``\`` character while in second it will represent exactly two ``\`` characters.

Comment: Then it looks like `a = a.replace("\\n", "\n");` will do the job? just like @Pshemo told you?

Comment: Also we don't know if in result you want to `\n` to represent two characters: ``\`` and `n`, or single character (line separator).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a java string variable as

```
String asd = "Some \\\\n text"
```

that means the engine already escapes from one `\` and you would see the value `\\n` on the debug console like `"Some \\n text"`. So if your original string on your text is `"Some \\\\n text"`, that means the java variable equivalent of this is

```
String asd = "Some \\\\\\\\n text"
```

That looks as `"Some \\\\n text"` in debug console. For this variable,

```
asd.replace("\\\\\\\\n","\\\\n")
```

would yield a value as `"Some \\n text"` in debug console. Hope this helps.